# Load external url in yii application content

Tags: php, yii

Is there some way to load external url like http://www.google.com in iframe,
like

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
'id'=>'cru-dialog',
'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Detail view',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'modal'=>false,
        'width'=>'95%',
        'height'=>800,
    ),
    ));
?>
<iframe id="cru-frame" width="80%" height="100%"></iframe>
<?php

$this->endWidget();
?>
```

Or any other way to load our desired URL in content of application.
Like when we click 
*mail* OR *MIS* OR *HR* links 
with logged in username and password from header, then 
*www.mail.myapp.com/?u=r&p=r* OR *www.mis.myapp.com?u=r&p=r* OR *www.hr.myapp.com?u=r&p=r* 
load in content.

Please help me out...

Comment: You can use clip to store the data and echo the clip to dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Partial View:

```
<?php $this->beginClip('externalUrl'); ?>
    <div class="cropDiv">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endClip();
echo $this->clips['externalUrl']; ?>
```

Now, bring the content of partial view from ajax and display it in dialogue box.
Example:

```
$("#cru-dialog").html(response).dialog("open");
```